# how to write nslookup programmatically?

Tags: php, python, ruby, networking, nslookup

instead of using exec in our script to do an nslookup, is there an easy way to write it programmatically in PHP, Python, or Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Socket Class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/classes/Socket.html#M004531) in Ruby. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993/reverse-dns-in-ruby/3012#3012).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, although the function names might not be what you expect.

Since the Python and Ruby answers are already posted, here is an PHP example:

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
$hostname = gethostbyaddr('127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python see http://small-code.blogspot.com/2008/05/nslookup-in-python.html . For much richer functionality, also in Python, see http://www.dnspython.org/ .

Comment: The documentation for the Python socket library http://pydoc.org/1.6/socket.html is also very useful. Have a look at:
gethostbyname() -- map a hostname to its IP number
gethostbyaddr() -- map an IP number or hostname to DNS info

Answer (score 1):

For PHP, you can use [gethostbyname](http://php.net/gethostbyname) and [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr).

For Python, import the socket module and again use [gethostbyname](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) and [gethostbyaddr](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyaddr).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
```

This will work but please be aware that it will be affected if the user changes their hosts file. You can't rely on it.