# Rails - Remote Domain Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A remote IP can be recive via: request.remote_ip (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/AbstractRequest.html). But is there a simple way to try to get the remote domain name (of this IP)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the answer to [Reverse DNS in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993/reverse-dns-in-ruby) which describes how to do reverse DNS lookups in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks! Also I have found this: 
    require 'resolv'
    Resolv.new.getname(request.remote_ip)